# Computing $ \int \frac{{\rm d} x}{x^3 + 12} $

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, rational-functions

$$ \int \frac{{\rm d} x}{x^3 + 12} $$

This is a question I came up with and have not been able to solve. I graphed this function and it is as in the picture attached. Some of the people who I have talked to have labeled it as an "impossible integral." Is it true or IS there actually a way to do this? I have recently started learning integration, but am really intrigued and curious.

Your help and explanation will mean a lot. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: after $x=\sqrt[3]{12}y$ to rewrite the integral as $12^{-2/3}\int\frac{dy}{y^3+1}$, find $A,\,B,\,C$ satisfying$$\frac{1}{y^3+1}=\frac{A}{y+1}+\frac{By+C}{y^2-y+1}$$(integrating the second fraction benefits from $z=y-\frac12$).

Answer (score 5):

First decompose the integrand into partial fractions
$$\frac{1}{x^3+a^3}=\frac{1}{(x+a)(x^2-ax+a^2)}=\frac{E}{x+a}+\frac{Fx+G}{x^2-ax+c}$$ where $a=12^{1/3}.$You shouln't have any trouble finding $E,F,G$ or in inegating the first fraction as a natural logarithm and the second fraction in terms of a natural logarithm and an arctan.

Answer (score 2):

Decompose the integrand into three manageable components below

$$\frac{1}{x^3+a^3}
=\frac{a(x+a) -x^2 +(x^2-ax+a^2)}{2a^2(x^3+a^3)}\\
=\frac1{2a^2}\left(\frac{a}{x^2-ax+a^2}-\frac{x^2}{x^3+a}+\frac{1}{x+a}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

here's a solution without decomposition.

substitute ->  x=cbrt(12y), as mentioned by a previous answerer,
this results in in the aforementioned integral (12^2/3)*integral of (1/y^3+1), then according to sum of cubes we have the following result
-> (y+1)(y^2-y+1)=y^3+1, hence y=tan(u), dy=sec2(u) as in secant squared of u or sec u times sec u, then we have the following tanu +1 times sec2(u)-tanu, that is after some algebraic manipulation, this becomes cos^2u/1-sinucosu.then u may continue with division

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).